# Necessity for Schengen visa if in possession of a valid red white red card plus

Tags: resident-permit, schengen, indian-citizens, austria

I am an Indian passport holder and have a red white red plus card valid till Jan 2025 (it was issued for 3 years). My employment in Austria ends on the 31st of August 2023 at which point I will move to the UK. My question is: can I still enter the Schengen area as long as my red white red card plus remains valid or will I need to apply for a Schengen visa every time I want to visit Austria or any other country in the Schengen area?

Comment: When you leave Austria, you must deregister your residence. Thus you are no longer a resident in Austria and the immigration authority will invalidate the **residence permit**. You will need a visitor visa to visit the Schengen Area.

Comment: @MarkJohnson That sounds like an answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

When you leave Austria, you must deregister your residence. Thus you are no longer a resident in Austria and the immigration authority will invalidate the **residence permit**.

You will need a visitor visa to visit the Schengen Area.

---

> [Validity of residence permits for third-country nationals - Bundesministerium für Inneres (Austria)](https://www.bmi.gv.at/312_en/13/start.aspx)
>
> **Possibility of losing a right of residence**
>
> The settlement authority can under certain conditions, withdraw a right of residence with an administrative decision or the right can automatically expire by law.
>
> This is the case, for example, with temporary residence titles if a third-country national is no longer resident in Austria. In this case, the authority must issue an official decision that the settlement in Austria has ended.
> ...